# iPhone - Writing a dictionary to file : handling errors

Tags: iphone, file, error-handling, nsdictionary

When saving a NSDictionary to file using :

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

YES or NO can be returned.

There are some methods for writing files that accept a NSError parameter.
In the case of the NSDictionary, such a method doesn't exist.

So if the `writeToFile`method returns NO, how may I know what happened ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the docs for `writeToFile:atomically:` to see which data types can be in a dictionary when you use this method. If you include an object not among these basic types (such as your own object), the method will return NO. In this case, to save these kinds of objects, you have to look to other means to write the data, such as using an NSArchiver and making your objects conform to the NSCoding protocol.

Comment: I guess there are many other kind of error that will lead to make the function return NO, doesn't it ?

Comment: Mostly it's that you tried to write out an object that the SDK didn't know how to deal with (because it's not one of the basic types that it can deal with.)

Comment: ok, but why would this method be different than others that handle an NSError object ?

Comment: That's the way Apple engineered it. :-) The constraints of using NSDictionary's writeToFile are pretty clear and straight forward. If it fails, it is more than likely because there is an object that cannot be written out "magically" like the base objects the method does support. There really is not telling why this method does not support an NSError argument while similar methods in other classes (e.g. NSData) do. Chalk it up to implementer's prerogative. :-)