# Dictionary not saving to file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, sandbox

I'm using the following code to save a NSMutableDictionary to file then retrieve it later.

The NSLog in the save method works fine, but the NSLog in retreive method logs null.

```
- (void)saveDataToFile
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cahchedTemplates"];
    [self.workflowTemplates writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE];
    NSLog(@"template save: %@", self.workflowTemplates);
}

- (IBAction)retrieveDataButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cahchedTemplates"];
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
    NSLog(@"tempDict: %@", tempDic);
}

+(NSMutableDictionary*)getClinicalTemplatesAndWorkFlowTemplates:(NSInteger)appointmentId
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ichrono/20110715/60b88126/fetch_clinical_templates/", [self getDrChronoHost]]];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    [self addCurrentUserLoginToPostRequest:request];
    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", appointmentId] forKey:@"appointment_id"];

    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSString *responseString;
    if (!error) {
        responseString = [request responseString];
    } else {
        //return [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Failed to connect to DrChrono.com, please check your WiFi or 3G connection."];
        NSMutableDictionary *returnContainer = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
        [returnContainer setObject:[[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"custom_templates"];
        [returnContainer setObject:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"workflow_templates"];
        return returnContainer;
    }

    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
    if ((NULL == responseDictionary) || (NULL == [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"errors"])) {
        NSMutableDictionary *returnContainer = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
        [returnContainer setObject:[[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"custom_templates"];
        [returnContainer setObject:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"workflow_templates"];
        return returnContainer;
    }

    NSMutableArray *templates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id it in [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"custom_templates"]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *clinical_template = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

        [clinical_template setValue:[it valueForKey:@"has_data_flag"] forKey:@"has_data_flag"];

        if (0) {
            //@note: mnusimow 20101010: Activate this code to put a "*" character at beginning of templates with values.
            if (0 != [[it valueForKey:@"has_data_flag"] intValue]) {
                [clinical_template setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@", [it valueForKey:@"name"]] forKey:@"display"];
            } else {
                [clinical_template setValue:[it valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"display"];
            }
        } else {
            [clinical_template setValue:[it valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"display"];
        }
        [clinical_template setValue:[it valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"template_id"];

        [templates addObject:clinical_template];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *returnContainer = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [returnContainer setObject:templates forKey:@"custom_templates"];
    [returnContainer setObject:[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"workflow_templates"] forKey:@"workflow_templates"];
    return returnContainer;
}
```

NSLog of self.workflowTemplate

```
2011-11-03 13:12:11.178 app[2869:1a603] sdfsafsafa:{
    "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    "hp_assessment" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77607;
    };
    "hp_cc_history_present_illness" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77603;
    };
    "hp_med_fam_social_history" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77604;
    };
    "hp_medications_allergies" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = "<null>";
    };
    "hp_physical_exam" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77606;
    };
    "hp_plan" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77608;
    };
    "hp_review_of_systems" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77605;
    };
    "soap_assessment" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77611;
    };
    "soap_objective" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77610;
    };
    "soap_plan" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77612;
    };
    "soap_subjective" =     {
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
        id = 77609;
    };
}
```

Edit:

Updated dictionary without `id object`

```
2011-11-03 16:28:31.136 app[11158:1a603] sdfsafsafa:{
    "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    "hp_assessment" =     {
        "db_id" = 77607;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "hp_cc_history_present_illness" =     {
        "db_id" = 77603;
        "has_data_flag" = 1;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "hp_med_fam_social_history" =     {
        "db_id" = 77604;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "hp_medications_allergies" =     {
        "db_id" = "<null>";
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "hp_physical_exam" =     {
        "db_id" = 77606;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "hp_plan" =     {
        "db_id" = 77608;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "hp_review_of_systems" =     {
        "db_id" = 77605;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "soap_assessment" =     {
        "db_id" = 77611;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "soap_objective" =     {
        "db_id" = 77610;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "soap_plan" =     {
        "db_id" = 77612;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
    "soap_subjective" =     {
        "db_id" = 77609;
        "has_data_flag" = 0;
        "has_manual_edits_flag" = 0;
    };
}
```

Comment: could you please share the description of the workflowTemplates before you save it and whether writeToFile returns true or false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `writeToFile:atomically:` returns a `BOOL`, which you should check. If it's failing, then you most likely have something in your dictionary which cannot be written out. Only the basic object types can be written out from a dictionary. See my answer to this question: [iPhone - Writing a dictionary to file : handling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806425/iphone-writing-a-dictionary-to-file-handling-errors) as well as the docs for `writeToFile:atomically:`.

Comment: `if (![self.workflowTemplates writeToFile:...]) { ...error... }`

Comment: I did this and it logged fail:  `if (![self.workflowTemplates writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE]) 
    { 
        NSLog(@"Fail");
    }`

Comment: So undoubtedly you have something in your dictionary that is not a basic type, as outlined in the docs (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary). If you have custom objects in there, `writeToFile:atomially:` will fail.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I have any though.  I just added the method which retreives the data from the server and I use this line to set it to `self.workflowTemplates`.  `self.workflowTemplates = [temp valueForKey:@"workflow_templates"];`

Comment: To be certain, dump (as I think you were already) the contents of workflowTemplates. There may very well be something that is not a basic type. Could be that you've down-cast something to simply `id` and that is too basic. :-)

Comment: What do you mean? To do this instead `self.workflowTemplates = temp;`? I did it and same result.

Comment: No, you were dumping to the log the contents of workflowTemplates with an NSLog statement, i.e. printing out the contents of the dictionary. What's in there? Anything without a specific type? Or, anything with a type other than one of the basic types?

Comment: Oh ok, I dumped workflow templates and posting results in question.

Comment: Entries like `id = 77607` look suspect to me... If `id` is the key, then that is the problem; the key itself appears to be an object of a type that is not a basic type (like an NSString, like all the other key values are).

Comment: Hmm.  I think it just just a key, no?  I use `id` with this line: `vc.customTemplateId = [[[self.workflowTemplates valueForKey:@"hp_cc_history_present_illness"] valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];`

Comment: Yeah, but `"id"` is different from `id`, as printed in the log output. I am certain this is the issue. If you can test by removing those `id` key's, and try saving the dictionary, I bet it works.

Comment: You may be right.  How can I determine what class `id` actually is?

Comment: Based on the `getClinicalTemplate....` method I have in the quesiton.  Isn't `id` just `[clinical_template setValue:[it valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"template_id"];`?

Comment: I'm wondering if this code: `for (id it in [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"custom_templates"])` isn't the root of the problem... unless the templates themselves contain objects of type `id`.

Comment: id is supposed to just be an int. perhaps it just needs a key name?

Comment: Yeah, make the key a string (NSString).

Comment: So I fixed the `id` issue and its now a key value with quotes.  But the write is still failing.

Comment: I'm adding the new NSLog of the workflowTemplates dictionary to the question.  It looks fine to me.

Comment: Let's verify the value of `filePath`.

Comment: I logged it and got `filepath: /Users/Me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/58C91A3E-1509-4FB7-9D9B-626061F32D3B/Documents/cachedTemplates`

Comment: Actually, is it because `[NSNull null]` is not allowed? and I have one key set to null?

Comment: Ok, so see if that file exists (probably not). See if the directory (.../Documents) exists. See if you have write access to that directory. Now we're grasping at every possibility. :-)

Comment: I got it working, it was because some values were set to NULL (see question), so I made those equal to 0 instead and it finally saves.